# How do I create a database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need a step by step procedure for creating a database in Android.

Comment: For more information I recommend you read the android documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html. It teaches you everything step by step. All the best

Answer (score 50):

Database is important thing in programming. Many of our codes always use data to be processed and saved. Just like any other programming environment, Android supports database programming too. You can use the default database supported by android, `SQLiteDatabase`.

Database in SQLiteDatabase can contain more than one table.Assume that we have one database `PERSONALDB` and one table `BIODATA`. The structure of `BIODATA` is:

```
_id integer
code string
name string
gender string

_id is for key increment,
```

`code`, `name`, and `gender` is for description of `person`.

When program is called for the first time, we have to make sure that the database and the table is opened, if it exists.If not, then we have to create a database and a table. As an example from `Android notepad sample`, here is the class `PersonDbHelper` for manipulating table `Biodata`.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class PersonDbHelper {
    class Row extends Object {
        public long _Id;
        public String code;
        public String name;
        public String gender;
    }

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table BIODATA(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "code text not null,"
            + "name text not null"
            +");";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PERSONALDB";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "BIODATA";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public PersonDbHelper(Context ctx) {
        try {
            db = ctx.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                db =
                    ctx.createDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, 0,
                        null);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                db = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    public void createRow(String code, String name) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("code", code);
        initialValues.put("name", name);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public void deleteRow(long rowId) {
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "_id=" + rowId, null);
    }

    public List<Row> fetchAllRows() {
        ArrayList<Row> ret = new ArrayList<Row>();
        try {
            Cursor c =
                db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    "_id", "code", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            int numRows = c.count();
            c.first();
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
                Row row = new Row();
                row._Id = c.getLong(0);
                row.code = c.getString(1);
                row.name = c.getString(2);
                ret.add(row);
                c.next();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Exception on query", e.toString());
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Row fetchRow(long rowId) {
        Row row = new Row();
        Cursor c =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                "_id", "code", "name"}, "_id=" + rowId, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c.count() > 0) {
            c.first();
            row._Id = c.getLong(0);
            row.code = c.getString(1);
            row.name = c.getString(2);
            return row;
        } else {
            row.rowId = -1;
            row.code = row.name= null;
        }
        return row;
    }

    public void updateRow(long rowId, String code, String name) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("code", code);
        args.put("name", name);
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "_id=" + rowId, null);
    }
    public Cursor GetAllRows() {
        try {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    "_id", "code", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Exception on query", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the method `onCreate`, you just have to put a single command given below to initialize the database :
...

```
Db = new PersonDbHelper(this);
```

...

It will try to open 'PersonalDB' first.If it does not exist, then it will create a database. In this 'PersonDbHelper' class, you have methods for inserting, deleting, updating, querying the table.

***Here is the reference to above tutorial:***

**[Creating my first android Database](http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-database.html)**

***You may also go through:***

**http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842**

**http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html**

Hope this helps.

Comment: would you please explain a little bit about the sql statement? "create table BIODATA(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "code text not null,"
            + "name text not null"
            +");"; why do we need "+" in between each column?

Comment: @Time You do not need +. It is just used as a concatenation operator. you can write it as: "create table BIODATA(_id integer primary key autoincrement, code text not null, name text not null);"

Answer (score 7):

Create database:

```
db= this.openOrCreateDatabase("db_hw3", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```