# work with database in android?

Tags: android

I wish to use database for my application.How to use the database in android.I use eclipse ide.Is there any **requirements** need for create database.Give some basic ideas about it.I am android beginner.Help me to know about it.

Comment: Please see this recent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227992/how-to-use-database-in-android

Comment: You may want to read the documentation for starters: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a database in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729438/how-do-i-create-a-database-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should see [Notepad sample project](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html). There are a lot of common android practices there including database stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is worded almost exactly like [how to use database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227992/how-to-use-database-in-android) I would say you created a duplicate question. if not, see that question. If you need more, supply the info you would like to the initial answerers.