# database name doesn't appear in file explorer eclipse uding sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my code,my database doesn't show in file explorer.does i make mistake??can anyone have a solution??

I'm sorry because im just beginner in android

```
package com.testmysqlite.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySqliteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String  dbName = "TestDatabase.db";
private static String tableName = "User";
private static String columnId = "Id";
private static String columnName = "Name";
private String sql = "create table "+tableName+"("+columnId+" integer,"+columnName+" text)";
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;
public MySqliteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
    sqliteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sql);// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729438/how-do-i-create-a-database-in-android)
[link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)