# setting up a database to be shipped in an android app and then have listview pull from it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to have a database in my app that my ListView will pull "name" from then display more data elsewhere in the same activity. It is a static database that will not be modified by the user in any way.

1. How do I make the database and have it in my app when shipped?
2. Can it be as easy as pulling from a spreadsheet in res/...?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just use simple data types, Strings, doubles, etc for information. Use an intent to start another activity with the rest of the information. You might check this other post out: [How do I create a database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729438/how-do-i-create-a-database-in-android).