# Failed to open database because db doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Filled in the form fields and then clicked 'Add Product' button and received the following error:

```
01-20 19:24:08.539: E/SQLiteLog(16936): (14) cannot open file at line 32516 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-20 19:24:08.539: E/SQLiteLog(16936): (14) os_unix.c:32516: (2) open(//ItemDatabase.db) - 
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936): Failed to open database 'ItemDatabase.db'.
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:339)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:236)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:859)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at com.example.fooditemmonitor.AddItem.onClick(AddItem.java:89)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-20 19:24:08.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(16936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 19:24:08.544: D/AndroidRuntime(16936): Shutting down VM
01-20 19:24:08.544: W/dalvikvm(16936): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c4d700)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:339)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:236)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:859)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at com.example.fooditemmonitor.AddItem.onClick(AddItem.java:89)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-20 19:24:08.554: E/AndroidRuntime(16936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ItemDatabase.java**

```
package com.example.fooditemmonitor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class ItemDatabase {

    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public ItemDatabase() {
    }

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class Database implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "foodItems";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE = "barcode";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY = "quantity";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date";
    }

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ", ";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
            + Database.TABLE_NAME + " (" + Database._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + Database.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Database.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Database.COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Database.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Database.COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + Database.TABLE_NAME;

    public class ItemDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database
        // version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDatabase.db";

        public ItemDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade
            // policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public static class ProductDatabase {
        String title;
        String barcode;
        double quantity;
    }
}
```

**AddItem.java**

```
package com.example.fooditemmonitor;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.fooditemmonitor.ItemDatabase.ProductDatabase;

public class AddItem extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText mBarcodeEdit;
    EditText mTitleEdit;
    EditText mQuantityEdit;
    private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
    private static final ProductDatabase mProductData = new ProductDatabase();
    private final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "foodItems";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDatabase.db";

    // a reference to the database used by this application/object
    ItemDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        db = new ItemDatabase();

        final Button mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Button mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Button currentInventory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToCurrent);
        currentInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddItem.this, CurrentItems.class));
            }
        });

        mBarcodeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcodeEdit);
        mTitleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        mQuantityEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityEdit);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.resetButton:
            mBarcodeEdit.setText("");
            mTitleEdit.setText("");
            mQuantityEdit.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.scanButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
            break;

        case R.id.addButton:
            String barcode = mBarcodeEdit.getText().toString();
            String title = mTitleEdit.getText().toString();
            String quantity = mQuantityEdit.getText().toString();

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            String errors = validateFields(barcode, title, quantity);
            if (errors.length() > 0) {
                showInfoDialog(this, "Please fix errors", errors);
            }

            else {
                // Insert user information here
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                mProductData.barcode = barcode;
                mProductData.title = title;
                mProductData.quantity = Double.valueOf(quantity);

                checkDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " VALUES ("
                        + getDateTime() + "," + mProductData + ")");
                checkDB.close();
                showInfoDialog(this, "Success", "Product saved successfully");
                resetForm();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
                Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    private void showInfoDialog(Context context, String title,
            String information) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(information)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void resetForm() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mBarcodeEdit.getText().clear();
        mTitleEdit.getText().clear();
        mQuantityEdit.getText().clear();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                mBarcodeEdit.setText(barcode);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String validateFields(String barcode, String title,
            String quantity) {
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

        if (barcode.matches("^\\s*$")) {
            errors.append("Barcode required - please scan\n");
        }

        if (title.matches("^\\s*$")) {
            errors.append("Please enter a title\n");
        }

        if (!quantity.matches("^-?\\d+(.\\d+)?$")) {
            errors.append("Please enter a numeric quantity\n");
        }

        return errors.toString();
    }
}
```

Have attempted to follow other tutorials but haven't helped! :/

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: you have a lot of vital mistakes, this is not a correct way to work with datebases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is error code=: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html.

`Please check your db exists in /data/data/packagename/database folder. Its not created/present. Please use context.openOrCreateDatabase() to create file.`

If your file is in asset folder its not writable file. You need to copy to sdcard/database folder of app

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729438/how-do-i-create-a-database-in-android) you should create your database if it doesn't exist, as your error said:

```
public PersonDbHelper(Context ctx) {
    try {
        db = ctx.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        try {
            db =
                ctx.createDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, 0,
                    null);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            db = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for simply copy pasting the referenced code, but I hope you get what you need to do here.