# My Activity cannot be connected with my Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, ddms

I have an activity named Awal.java and the code :

```
public class Awal extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


    private Cursor kategori;
    private MyDatabase db;
    private List<String> ktg;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            db = new MyDatabase(this, null);
            ktg = db.getKategori();



            String namaKtg[] = ktg.toArray(new String[ktg.size()]);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, R.id.label, namaKtg));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        kategori.close();
        db.close();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long l) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Awal.this,Detail.class);
        intent.putExtra("namaKategori", adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and also databaseHelper named MyDatabase.java and here is the code :

```
package com.mroring.belajarperancis;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Variable declaration
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.mroring.belajarperancis/databases/";
    public static String DB_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    private final Context myContext;
    private String strMypath;


    public MyDatabase(Context context, String DB_NAME) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            MyDatabase.DB_NAME = DB_NAME;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        try {
            // check if the database exists
            boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
            if (!dbExist) {
                // database is not present copy databse
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDatabse(DB_NAME);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        try {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            return dbFile.exists();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    public void copyDatabse(String DB_NAME) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Open your local db as the input stream
            Input`enter code here`Stream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 2];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                try {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            if (myOutput != null) {
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
            }
            if (myInput != null)
                myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function is used to open the database
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        // Open the database
        try {
            strMypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(strMypath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
    }


        public List<String> getKategori() {
            String query = "SELECT _id FROM kategori";
            List<String> kategori = new ArrayList<String>();

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            //looping through
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    kategori.add(cursor.getString(0)); // add id & nama
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return kategori;
        }

        public List<List<String>> getDetail(String namaKategori) {
            String query = "select pra, ina, baca from kata,kategori where kata.id_kategori=kategori._id and kategori.nama = '"+namaKategori+"'";
            List<List<String>> detail = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            //looping
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
                    item.add(cursor.getString(0)); //add french word
                    item.add(cursor.getString(1)); //add indonesian word
                    item.add(cursor.getString(2)); //add baca
                    detail.add(item);
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return detail;
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            copyDatabse(DB_NAME);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

And this combination always makes errors and here are the error :

```
06-18 01:23:01.694: E/AndroidRuntime(17219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mroring.belajarperancis/com.mroring.belajarperancis.Awal}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kategori: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM kategori
06-18 01:23:01.694: E/AndroidRuntime(17219): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kategori: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM kategori
```

I have a database named 'MY_DATABASE' in .../BelajarPerancis/assets/databases/MY_DATABASE and also .../BelajarPerancis/assets/MY_DATABASE (I tried to put the DB in two places).

I have tried to pull the database from DDMS, and it returns the same Database with the same contents/tables and it has table 'Kategori'.

My 'Kategori' table contains the field of '_id' and here is the proof `3 Rows returned from: select nama from kategori; (took 5ms)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are passing database name as null in line `db = new MyDatabase(this, null);`
2. I can not see code to create 'kategori' table 
   and in query you are trying to get data from table name as 'kategori' `String query = "SELECT _id FROM kategori";` which do not exists..

Change `db = new MyDatabase(this, null);` to 
  `db = new MyDatabase(this, "SOME_DATABASE_NAME");`

and then write code to create table in database.

Activity launch is not working because `db.getKategori();` is called from `onCreate()` method and which is throwing exception.

please go through http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: I only changed the 'null' into my database name and it works ! Thanks a lot. May God Bless You :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you create the database?

I say that because you're using a absolute path to get the file of the database, the best thing to do in that case is create a database as the standard of Google.

here is a good answer, of how do that:

[How do I create a database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729438/how-do-i-create-a-database-in-android)

You can check too the name of your table, if you use with the first letter in uppercase you must use in that way all time.

att.